# Using CD4053 for arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, pins

I would like to use CD4053 for multiplexing in arduino but the problem is that I don't understand how CD4053 works, is it the same as CD4051, can someone help me, provide example code and circuit??

Comment: Have you looked at the datasheet yet?

Comment: Yeah but I really don't understand how it works

Comment: You should tell us what you want to achieve, nit how you think it should be done. The 4053 may be a fine choice for your need - or may not be needed at all. Also - provide datasheet link to things you ask about to save need for N people to look up same thing to help you. What is the application? 4051 is a 1 of 8 bidirectional analog selector. You supply 3 address lines which can have 8 address states (000 001 010 011 ... ) and these connect 1 of 8 input / outputs to one master ouput/input. | A 4053 is 3 x SPDT switches. each switch is controlled by it's own enable lead. **BUT**

Comment: ... if you do not know how a CD4053 works you cannot possibly know that you need to use one or how to do so in any meaningful way. SO tell us what you are trying to achieve. || [CD 4051-53 data sheet](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/CD4051BC.pdf)

Comment: I am actually trying to add more IO pins for my arduino, so I researched and found out that I should use 4051. Then I went to my local electronic shop but they don't have 4051 instead they gave me 4053. Here is the link of the arduino tutorial: http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/4051 :))

Comment: -1 for stating a vague problem and directly demanding a full solution (explanation, circuit and source code).

Answer (score 0):

Consider one of the many I2C I/O boards (search for i2c expander on eBay) that can be purchased for a few bucks.  They are also available from many of the people that support Arduino.   It then only requires 2 pins from the Arduino for up to 8 external devices which can have from 8, 16 and sometimes more I/O per board.  They can be used as input or output.

You can also operate several displays on the same two pins as the I/O.

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

The 4053 can replace the 4051 ([data sheet](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/CD4051BC.pdf)). To do that the three output pins on 4053 should be tied together (pin 4, 14 and 15, see logic diagram).

The device allows adding eight analog pins at the cost of three digital pins and one analog pin. The device will multiplex the eight new analog pins onto the arduino analog pin. Three digital pins are used to select which pin is multiplexed.

The arduino [tutorial](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/4051) for 4051 will work just fine with the above modification of the wiring.

Cheers!